# How to authenticate a User and Login him using the API response?

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I know Laravel provides the greate authentication system by using

```
php artisan make:auth
```

But in my situation

I am trying to authenticate the user and login him by using some API response instead of a database. 
I have to submit the login form data to this URL

http://evf.dndaims.net/api/User?userName=admin&Password=adminpassword

This URL responds with the true or false and base on this I want to log in the user

Here is the success Response

```
{
Success: true,
Message: "Successful login",
ErrorCode: 0,
iUserId: 1,
iUserRole: 1
}
```

Using the role I want to send him a specific view. Like role 1 is for admin role 2 is for the user. I know the middleware technique but how to use it with this situation?

I tried to do it in many ways but no success. I tried to use JWT but still no success. 
Can anyone suggest me the best way to implement that in laravel?

Comment: You could use passport, middleware, or auth guards to do this as well.

Comment: Is it possible with passport? I don't want to interact with the local database. I just have a JSON response and now also receiving a token with it. How can I authenticate the user using that token? As soon as the form is submited it will get the JSON response if the response is a success and get the token it should start the loggin session. Hope you get my point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel `jwt package`  from this url :
[Here](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) and follow all steps to install it , and you can use `jwt auth` middleware .

I think this article will help you [Here](https://blog.pusher.com/laravel-jwt/)

Comment: Is it possible with JWT? I don't want to interact with the local database. I just have a JSON response and now also receiving a token with it. How can I authenticate the user using that token?

As soon as the form is submited it will get the JSON response if the response is a success and get the token it should start the loggin session. Hope you get my point.

Comment: okay , please check this article 
https://medium.com/@miladrahimi/laravel-jwt-guard-and-authentication-tools-introducing-larajwt-package-6ff3e16ac105

You can get the user from his toke by using `JwtAuth::retrieveUse` ,

You can use postman to test it

Comment: This package expires now and recommends the passport. Passport is not useful for as I don't have any database.
Just can use API's response for everything.